# Rename the Meta tag [flag-suspension] to [flag-ban]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, meta

Can we rename here on Meta the tag [flag-suspension](/questions/tagged/flag-suspension) to [flag-ban](/questions/tagged/flag-ban)?

I don't think there are *suspensions* as such used in the context of flags. Even moderators call them bans.

The tag wiki and excerpt also speaks of bans, the [dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQtQA.png) the user sees when they are flag-banned doesn't use the word suspension. Only the name of the tag is bothered with introducing that word. Even on MSE there is no [flag-suspension tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flag-ban)

Please rename the tag [flag-suspension](/questions/tagged/flag-suspension) to [flag-ban](/questions/tagged/flag-ban). No bans or flags should be hurt in this process.

Comment: Whereas I fully agree that the phrase 'ban' is used more consistently in reference to a  flag-suspension, I personally still perceive a 'suspension' more clearly as a word referring to something 'temporary' - while a ban could be perceived as something rather permanent as well..

Comment: @iLuvLogix not in Stack Exchange. Chat ban is maximum year long, and post ban is lifted once the user improves their posts and get upvotes. Neither are permanent.

Comment: I'm so looking forward to have this language lawyer debate ...

Comment: @rene just don't look back! ;)

Comment: @Shadow actually - chat bans can be specified in hours up to N many digits - it's not impossible to issue a ban for something like 400 years...

Comment: @JonClements oh, so 9999 hours which are 416 days?

Comment: Can't remember - there's a limit on the number of digits and 9999 seems reasonable. However, if you turn off the form validation/construct the request manually you can send a ridiculously large number and the system will accept it ;)

Comment: I tried to change it myself, but I got flag banned. Help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Renamed/merged tag, [28 questions with the tag have been updated.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bflag-ban%5D+is%3Aq)

```
updating post history, 32 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 28 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
Master tag 'flag-ban' doesn't exist, renaming to 'flag-suspension'
rename result: 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [flag-ban] and [flag-suspension] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym flag-suspension -> flag-ban was approved!
```

Comment: You needed [the meta reputation](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/44932302#44932302) ... ;)